# \foreach with two or more variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I often find myself wanting to use some feature that allows me to loop through several sets where the nth item in each list is paired together with the nth item in the other lists.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
% Let's say I have several values to label on the graph
\foreach \x in {1,5,6,2,1,6,3,1}
\foreach \y in {0,3,4,0.5,2,3,1.5,4}
\foreach \point in {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}
\draw [fill = black] (\x,\y) circle (1 mm) node[left] {\point};
% This draws every combination from the three lists which is a huge mess!

% What I want it to draw is
\draw [fill = black] (4,2)      circle (1 mm) node[left] {A};
\draw [fill = black] (5,3)      circle (1 mm) node[left] {B};
\draw [fill = black] (6,4)      circle (1 mm) node[left] {C};
\draw [fill = black] (2,0.5)    circle (1 mm) node[left] {D};
\draw [fill = black] (1,2)      circle (1 mm) node[left] {E};
\draw [fill = black] (6,3)      circle (1 mm) node[left] {F};
\draw [fill = black] (3,1.5)    circle (1 mm) node[left] {G};
\draw [fill = black] (1,4)      circle (1 mm) node[left] {H};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a clean, easy way to do this?

Comment: like this `\foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/2/3,4/5/6}{...}`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach\x/\y/\z in {4/2/A,5/3/B,6/4/C,2/.5/D,1/2/E,6/3/F,3/1.5/G,1/4/H}
  \draw [fill = black] (\x,\y)circle (1 mm) node[left] {\z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Like this? Are you unsure?

Comment: You can probably use two variables like this `\foreach\p/\z in {(4,2)/A,(5,3)/B,(6,4)/C,(2,.5)/D,(1,2)/E,(6,3)/F,(3,1.5)/G,(1,4)/H}` with `\p` in place of `(\x,\y)` ? Or only one like this `\foreach[count=\z from 65]\p in {(4,2),(5,3),(6,4),(2,.5),(1,2),(6,3),(3,1.5),(1,4)}` with `\char\z` in place of `\z` ?

Answer (score 7):

Also with `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=left,xmin=0,ymin=0, xmax=7.5, ymax=7.5]
\addplot+[only marks, nodes near coords=\csname @Alph\endcsname{\numexpr\coordindex+1}] 
     coordinates {(4,2)(5,3)(6,4)(2,0.5)(1,2)(6,3)(3,1.5)(1,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]